# Trouble plotting probability

Tags: data-visualization, density-function, notation

I have a density function that can be written as follows:

$$ f(r) = \frac{(1-r^2)^{\frac{n-4}{2}}}{\mathbf{B}\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{n-2}{2}\right)}$$

Where $\mathbf{B}$ is the beta function. I got this from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Using_the_exact_distribution), it is the distribution of sample product-moment correlations between two uncorrelated gaussians.

I want to numerically solve $P\{-v < r < v\}$ for some $v$, and make a plot of the probability as a function of $n$. But I don't know how to use the beta function in the denominator, in the equation it looks like a function that has not been resolved into a scalar. Shouldn't it be also a function of $r$? The equation seems like it is in a broken form.

Comment: Why not use `pbeta`?  It was designed for this calculation.  The solution is `pbeta((1+x)/2,n/2-1,n/2-1) - pbeta((1-x)/2,n/2-1,n/2-1)`

Comment: Probably because not everybody is capable of recognizing the link to the beta distribution :-). Me, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
productdensity <- function(r,n) (1-r^2)^((n-4)/2)/beta(1/2,(n-2)/2) 
v <- .1
n <- seq(10,100,by=10)
areas <- rep(NA,length(n))
for (i in 1:length(n)){
  areas[i] <- integrate(productdensity,-v,v,n=n[i])$value  
}
plot(n,areas,type="l")
```

The loop apparently may be avoided as follows - but not my area of expertise:

```
productdensity <- function(r,n) (1-r^2)^((n-4)/2)/beta(1/2,(n-2)/2) 
area <- function(v,n) integrate(productdensity,-v,v,n=n)$value 
v <- .1
ns <- as.matrix(seq(10,100,by=10))
areas2 <- apply(ns,1,FUN=area,v=v)
plot(ns,areas2,type="l")
```

Comment: Do you happen to know which would be faster? Both are sufficient for this problem, but I would not bother making it modular if it didn't introduce any speed up.

Comment: That could be assessed with the microbechmark package. Conventional wisdom has it that loops are slower.